# Activity Started by TAG_DISCOVERED Shows Incorrect Name and Icon in Recent Apps Drawer

Tags: android, nfc

I'm starting the application using an intent filter to catch the `TAG_DISCOVERED` action. See my intents below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The application starts correctly, but when opening the Recent Apps drawer, I am presented with the Bluetooh / NFC icon and an application name of `NFC Service`.

The icons all work correctly if I manually launch my application from the launcher- it's only incorrect when launched by the `TAG_DISCOVERED` action.

Is there a way to override the icon and name set by this action?

[image: Incorrect Name and Icon]

Answer (score 1):

Specify an `android:label` and an `android:icon` in your activity tag.

If that doesn't work, wrap each intent-filter within their own activity xml set of tags and specify the same `android:label` and the same `android:icon` for each activity.

Here is their [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: I tried adding an `android:icon` into my activity tag (`android:label` was already there), but nothing has changed. I'm not sure what you mean by _wrapping each intent-filter within their own activity xml set of tags`. Can you clarify this? Thanks (:

Comment: You could enclose each intent-filter within a different activity (in other words, direct each intent-filter to a separate activity). Those two different activities could have the same label and icon and would look the same to the user otherwise.